# Firefox 13 broke selenium tests

Tags: firefox, automated-tests, selenium-rc, selenium-firefoxdriver

Apparently I upgraded my Firefox this morning along with some other system updates and now my selenium tests are broken! They worked fine yesterday and all passed. Performing hovers seems to be an issue.
This is the error I got:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "sel.py", line 201, in testAddContent
hoveredElement.perform()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/action_chains.py", line 44, in perform
action()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/action_chains.py", line 201, in <lambda>
self._driver.execute(Command.MOVE_TO, {'element': to_element.id}))
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 155, in execute
self.error_handler.check_response(response)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 147, in check_response
raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
InvalidElementStateException: Message: u'Cannot perform native interaction: Could not load native events component.' ; Stacktrace: Method generateErrorForNativeEvents threw an error in file:///tmp/tmpq2yHMn/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver_component.js
```

Comment: you will have to either downgrade Firefox or wait for selenium upgrade. Firefox came out yesterday AFAIK. Not enbough time to even start working on updates I think...

Comment: really? that's the only solution? hm, geez...ok. Thanks a lot, hopefully selenium will upgrade soon!

Comment: You cannot expect everyone to verify their apps work a day after Firefox 13 comes out.

Comment: @Arran Quite true, although there are Mozilla folks on the Selenium development team who try to keep it within a few days.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need Selenium 2.23, which was released yesterday.

Comment: Thanks, I have been busy, by the time I did upgrade Selenium, Selenium 2.24 was out and the tests ran fine in FF13. (Didn't actually try Selenium 2.23)

Answer (score 2):

One option is to run against an older version of Firefox.  I include an older copies of firefox in the source tree to test SizSelCsZzz (https://github.com/fschwiet/SizSelCsZzz/tree/master/browser_archive).  For C#, using such an exe is like:

```
var firefoxProfile = new FirefoxProfile();
var browser = new FirefoxDriver(new FirefoxBinary(exePath), firefoxProfile);
```